# Set background-image for button to element already contained within page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I want to specify the background-image for a button using something other than an image url. Being able to set the background-image to an already loaded  element contained within the DOM would be ideal. This is so that I can cache a loading gif (displayed on the button) within the DOM and don't have to fetch it when the button is clicked.

I didn't think code was necessary to illustrate the problem but here is some anyway

Not ideal due to image loading on click:

```
    that.submitButtonSelector.css('background-image', 'url(/Content/_activity/ajax-loader.gif)');
```

Ideal (but no obvious way to achieve)

```
    that.submitButtonSelector.css('background-image', '#precachedImage');
```

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be welcome. Searching didn't reveal a solution to this issue.

Comment: a can think of a reason: Where is your code ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: maybe the downvoter would like to see what is your current code and if you have tried anything so far (No, I'm not the downvoter, just my 2 cents =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the loading gif via the url, it will be cached in most cases.  You only need to download it once.  After that it will be served up from cache.  The only other thing I can think of is to use a base64 source.  This has the benefit if not generating an HTTP request, but is larger when it comes to actual bytes (I don't think the larger size is slower than another HTTP request, but you can always benchmark them).

In my experience I believe base64 images are great if you need to immediately show the loading icon and if the icon is small enough, but if you don't need to show it right away, I suggest preloading the image via url with javascript and just relying on the cached version.

So in your case, if you went with base64, you could use

```
that.submitButtonSelector.css('background-image', 'url(data:image/gif;base64,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)');
```

```css
body:after {
  content: url(data:image/gif;base64,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)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a hidden div that preloads the image into cache, and then once it's loaded you can add the background.

HTML:

```
<img id="img" src="/Content/_activity/ajax-loader.gif" />
```

CSS:

```
#img {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#img").load(function() {
    $(submitButtonSelector).click(function() {
        that.submitButtonSelector.css("background-image", "/Content/_activity/ajax-loader.gif");
    });
});
```